# problema con ñ en diccionario en python

Tags: python, utf-8

estoy definiendo un diccionario con un elemento con ñ pero da error

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__author__ = "equipo"
__date__ = "$02-may-2017 9:23:20$"

if __name__ == "__main__":

SustantivoMS = {
    'perro':'PERRO',
    'gato':'GATO',
    'niño':'NIÑO',
    'arbol':'ARBOL'   
}
```

este es el error `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xf1' in file C:\Users\equipo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProyectoLenguajeInterprete\src\proyectolenguajeinterprete.py on line 42, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

Comment: ¿Estás guardando tu archivo como utf8? ¿Ejecutas tu archivo desde el intérprete de comandos o desde una terminal interna en NetBeans? ¿Existe una codificación de lenguaje definida en tus variables de entorno. Si, cuál?

Comment: desde NetBeans, la verdad la codificación definida en las variables de entorno la desconozco @toledano

Comment: ¿Podrías ejecutar tu programa desde `cmd.exe` o desde PowerShell? A veces los IDE usan un proxy para ejecutar los scripts que capturan la salida que te muestran y este _proxy_ podría no estar preparado para manejar utf8.

Comment: me da el mismo error @toledano ya lo ejecute por consola

Comment: Verifica la codificación con la que estás guardando tu archivo. Debería ser utf8.

Comment: Como lo verifico? y perdona la ignorancia @toledano

Comment: Yo también lo ignoro. Consulta la documentación del programa que usas.

Comment: listo, con notepad++ lo hice era la configuración @toledano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes forzar las cadenas a ser interpretadas explícitamente como Unicode simplemente agregando una **u** a la definición de la cadena.

Prueba con:

```
SustantivoMS = {
u'perro': u'PERRO',
u'gato': u'GATO',
u'niño': u'NIÑO',
u'arbol': u'ARBOL'   
}
```

Si esto no tiene efecto, asegúrate que tú editor de textos esté efectivamente usando codificación UTF8 para grabar el texto codificado y no alguna codificacion exótica como ASCII de 7 bits o CP418, que solía ser común en ambientes Xenix cuando los dinosaurios caminaban en la tierra y Microsoft licenciaba un SO UNIX Genuino.